# Serve text/html from wp-json API via WPEngine, headers not being set properly

Tags: plugin-development, html, headers, rest-api

I have read multiple entries in the WP Codex, numerous articles and Stack Exchange questions. I have a fully functioning API for a private plugin I am developing, but when moving it into production on WPEngine, the endpoint that served `text/html` is having CORS and CORBS issues. I have tried setting the headers just for that route but nothing seems to be working. It worked fine locally, and on our dev servers.

**Why serve `HTML` you ask?**

My plugin connects a WP form I created in React.JS, via an Admin Portal, with our CRM, via another API from our IIS .Net Server. Once someone submits a form, the API takes over the transaction and matches `HTML` I serve with some other internal data to send an email. We want to keep this system centralized for security, maintenance and more importantly cross-platform purposes (We have other tech stacks we serve).

**So What is Happening?**

I can hit my endpoint from the browser and the html renders. I can even get the html from RESTlet/Postman. However, when I try to make a `GET` request to the URL from our internal API, the server is not allowing the request.

**Here is the setup:**

*Sending Response*

```
//callback for register_rest_route
function proxy_email($request) {
    //some validation, db queries and other stuff

    header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );
    echo $html_email;
    exit();
}
```

*Handling Cors*

```
//handling cors
remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );
add_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function( $served, $result, $request, $server ) {
    $origin = get_http_origin();
    $route = $request->get_route();
    $allowed_origins = array(
        //the local, dev, and production origins plus the following:
        site_url()
    );

    // the route I set up for the email includes the string 'thankyou'

    if ( $origin && in_array( $origin, $allowed_origins ) && preg_match( "/(thankyou)/", $route ) != 1) {
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . esc_url_raw( $origin ) );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-WP-Nonce');

    } else if ( $origin && in_array( $origin, $allowed_origins ) && preg_match( "/(thankyou)/", $route ) == 1 ) {
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . esc_url_raw( $origin ) );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET');
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
        header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        header( 'Accept: */*');
    }
    return $served;

}, 10, 4);
```

Is there an issue with my approach, is this a WP issue, or is this a WPEngine Issue, or is this something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone encounters this exact problem in the future:

I found the error to be related to the external api not being properly configured to handle a request to a secure endpoint.

Since my site on WPEngine is secure (`https`), IIS needs to be configured to handle TLS1.2, which is wasn't (start here for the crumb trail : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627977/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send).

The configuration in my question works as designed, though perhaps it could be better designed (you let me know!). The server calling this endpoint wasn't configured properly.